# Lazy Load Background Images Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I want to lazy load background images 
so i need to convert

```
<div class="post-header post-tp-11-header" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.guest.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/A-Beautiful-Message-for-Anyone-Who-is-Searching-For-Love-750x430.jpg);">
```

to

```
<div class="post-header post-tp-11-header" data-original="https://cdn.guest.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/A-Beautiful-Message-for-Anyone-Who-is-Searching-For-Love-750x430.jpg">
```

[style may contain two or more attributes, only the background image attribute should be removed ]

Which i have partially got working using the following PHP [Source](https://github.com/lipemat/Lazy-Load-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/lazy-load.php) but it only works with **a** tags it is not working with any **div**

```
static function add_background_placeholders( $content ) {
    // Don't lazyload for feeds, previews, mobile
    if( is_feed() || is_preview() || ( function_exists( 'is_mobile' ) && is_mobile() ) )
        return $content;
    // Don't lazy-load if the content has already been run through previously
    if ( false !== strpos( $content, 'data-background' ) )
        return $content;
    preg_match_all('~\bstyle=(\'|")(.*?)background(-image)?\s*:(.*?)\(\s*(\'|")?(?<image>.*?)\3?\s*\)~i',$content,$matches);

    if( empty( $matches ) ) return $content;

    foreach( $matches[0] as $match ){
         preg_match('~\bbackground(-image)?\s*:(.*?)\(\s*(\'|")?(?<image>.*?)\3?\s*\)~i',$match,$bg);              
         $bg_less_match = str_replace( $bg[0], '', $match );             
         $data_match = 'data-background="'.$bg['image'].'" '.$bg_less_match;
         $content = str_replace( array($match.';', $match), array( $data_match, $data_match), $content);
    }

  return $content;
}
```

I have tried my best to sort it out but couldn't find a solution

[Mods: Please correct this questions if there anything wrong]

Answer (score 1):

The function in your question will actually search through **div**'s by default. I have tested it here: https://regex101.com/r/HunEXt/1.

The problem may be that you are not passing the correct content as a parameter.

---

Also, make sure you are changing the line

`$data_match = 'data-background="'.$bg['image'].'" '.$bg_less_match;`

to

`$data_match = 'data-original="'.$bg['image'].'" '.$bg_less_match;`

to get your desired data attribute.

Comment: Yes i have changed that but it is not working with **div** tags

Comment: Then I suggest finding out exactly what the value of $content is when you are using this function.